# Mounting hard-drive on boot

Tags: mount, fstab

I had 2 HDD, today I bought a new one, I would like to mount this HDD at boot, it's working, but the new HDD mounted under robu not root, why?

Content of the fstab:

```
UUID=8e492a04-c05d-4861-b996-a36ebbaf3d43 /media/WESYS_RAID    ext4   rw 0       0

UUID=12C81F25C81F071F  /media/WESYS_DATA  ntfs defaults,iocharset=utf8    0   0

/dev/mapper/WeSyS_LVM /media/WESYS_LVM ext4     rw 0    0
```

This is the rights.

```
drwxrwxrwx 1 root  root  4096 2012-04-05 11:51 WESYS_DATA
drwxr-xr-x 9 root  root  4096 2012-03-01 10:11 WESYS_LVM
drwx------ 3 robu  robu  4096 2012-04-10 12:33 WESYS_RAID
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'mounted under robu'? Is 'robu' a contraction for something? Does it say 'robu' or '/robu' because those are not the same thing. Can you please include more details?

Comment: robu is the user, not a folder

Comment: So, are you then trying to say that the new drive is mounting as /robu or /home/robu ? Or more likely, did you mean that the drive, after being mounted, is owned by the user 'robu' and not root?

Comment: yes exactly, sorry I'm not a native English speaker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the options you have listed in `/etc/fstab` to something like `defaults, user` which is the same as `rw,suid,dev,exec,auto,user,async`. This should allow any user of the system to mount the device. The owner of the block device is what is listed in your second output. That can be changed by chown'ing the block device, but shouldn't be needed if you change the permissions of the folders under the root folder of that device.

Good Resources:
[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fstab#ext2)
[Tuxfiles](http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/fstab.html)

Comment: I can confirm my suspicion if you post the output of `ls -l /dev/sd* /dev/mapper` and add it to your question.